# How to improve the count of unique values to illustrate cleaner format

Tags: sql, count, sum, case

Column order_cd has two unique values = SGL, DBL.
I am trying to get the count of these for each store number in a location. I am able to get the count with my code below but would like to learn how to get it into the desired format in sql.

```
SELECT 
Location, store_nm,
,SUM(CASE WHEN order_cd = 'SGL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS Single
,SUM(CASE WHEN order_cd = 'DBL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS Double
From Table
```

```
**Current state
+----------+----------+--------+---------+
| Location | Store_nm | Single | Double  |
+----------+----------+--------+---------+
|     E    |   10     |   123  |   0     |
|     E    |   10     |    0   |   2     |
|     E    |   30     |    55  |   0     |
|     E    |   30     |    0   |   65    |
|     E    |   45     |   1456 |   0     |
|     E    |   45     |   0    |   800   |
+----------+----------+--------+---------+

**DESIRED**
+----------+----------+--------+---------+
| Location | Store_nm | Single | Double  |
+----------+----------+--------+---------+
|     E    |   10     |   123  |    2    |
|     E    |   30     |   55   |    65   |
|     E    |   45     |  1456  |   800   |
+----------+----------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Add `GROUP BY Location, store_nm` to the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by user FlexYourData.

`Add GROUP BY Location, store_nm to the end of your query.`

Thank you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).